# Solidity to inline assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly

Taken a smart contract like the following:

```
contract A {
    address public beneficiary;

    function A(address _beneficiary) public {
         beneficiary = _beneficiary;
    }

    function () public payable {
         beneficiary.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

How would you write it in inline assembly? No problem for me with the constructor, but got stuck with the fallback function, since I don't know how to translate the transfer()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this, using call() to do an external function call, passing the msg.value inside it.

```
function () payable {
    bytes4 sig = bytes4(keccak256("()")); // function signature

    assembly {
        let x := mload(0x40) // get empty storage location
        mstore ( x, sig ) // 4 bytes - place signature in empty storage

        let ret := call (gas, 
            beneficiary,
            msg.value, 
            x, // input
            0x04, // input size = 4 bytes
            x, // output stored at input location, save space
            0x0 // output size = 0 bytes
        )

        mstore(0x40, add(x,0x20)) // update free memory pointer
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also call the fallback also if you pass an empty input.

Comment: Thank you @Elizabeth! I had to change something like `beneficiary` and `msg.value` with `sload(beneficiary_slot)` and `callvalue` but it is correct. Two more questions:
1. I tried to change input, output and sizes with `0x0` as suggested by @Ismael and it worked, but I don't know if it's like a bad practice. Do I have to always specify input and output in `call` opcode even if I forward funds like in this case?
2. Updating free memory pointer is a best practice?

Comment: @Ismael, yep the fallback will be called with an empty input or any invalid input, eg. `thisIsNotAFunction()`.  in this case, since we're calling the fallback and don't need input or output I don't think it matters. I just like to keep input and output there for clarity. If you're calling a function that takes parameters, then you would need to pass them in through the input, and get the return value from the output. yeah updating the free memory pointer is a good idea. it's necessary if we're using the return value of the call.

Comment: Hey, I would love to see this but modified such that I could also pass some arbitrary call data to it?

Answer (score -1):

Run `solc --asm --output-dir=build/binaries A.sol`.

Then just take whatever is in the file `build/binaries/A.evm`.

With `pragma solidity ^0.4.18` I got the following piece of code:

```
    /* "contracts/A.sol":26:254  contract A {
... */
  mstore(0x40, 0x60)
    /* "contracts/A.sol":79:165  function A(address _beneficiary) public {
... */
  jumpi(tag_1, iszero(callvalue))
  0x0
  dup1
  revert
tag_1:
  mload(0x40)
  0x20
  dup1
  bytecodeSize
  dup4
  codecopy
  dup2
  add
  0x40
  mstore
  dup1
  dup1
  mload
  swap1
  0x20
  add
  swap1
  swap2
  swap1
  pop
  pop
    /* "contracts/A.sol":145:157  _beneficiary */
  dup1
    /* "contracts/A.sol":131:142  beneficiary */
  0x0
  dup1
    /* "contracts/A.sol":131:157  beneficiary = _beneficiary */
  0x100
  exp
  dup2
  sload
  dup2
  0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
  mul
  not
  and
  swap1
  dup4
  0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
  and
  mul
  or
  swap1
  sstore
  pop
    /* "contracts/A.sol":79:165  function A(address _beneficiary) public {
... */
  pop
    /* "contracts/A.sol":26:254  contract A {
... */
  dataSize(sub_0)
  dup1
  dataOffset(sub_0)
  0x0
  codecopy
  0x0
  return
stop

sub_0: assembly {
        /* "contracts/A.sol":26:254  contract A {
... */
      mstore(0x40, 0x60)
      jumpi(tag_1, lt(calldatasize, 0x4))
      calldataload(0x0)
      0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      swap1
      div
      0xffffffff
      and
      dup1
      0x38af3eed
      eq
      tag_2
      jumpi
    tag_1:
        /* "contracts/A.sol":212:223  beneficiary */
      0x0
      dup1
      swap1
      sload
      swap1
      0x100
      exp
      swap1
      div
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      and
        /* "contracts/A.sol":212:232  beneficiary.transfer */
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      and
        /* "contracts/A.sol":212:243  beneficiary.transfer(msg.value) */
      0x8fc
        /* "contracts/A.sol":233:242  msg.value */
      callvalue
        /* "contracts/A.sol":212:243  beneficiary.transfer(msg.value) */
      swap1
      dup2
      iszero
      mul
      swap1
      mload(0x40)
      0x0
      mload(0x40)
      dup1
      dup4
      sub
      dup2
      dup6
      dup9
      dup9
      call
      swap4
      pop
      pop
      pop
      pop
      iszero
      iszero
      tag_5
      jumpi
      0x0
      dup1
      revert
    tag_5:
        /* "contracts/A.sol":26:254  contract A {
... */
      stop
        /* "contracts/A.sol":44:70  address public beneficiary */
    tag_2:
      jumpi(tag_6, iszero(callvalue))
      0x0
      dup1
      revert
    tag_6:
      tag_7
      jump(tag_8)
    tag_7:
      mload(0x40)
      dup1
      dup3
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      and
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      and
      dup2
      mstore
      0x20
      add
      swap2
      pop
      pop
      mload(0x40)
      dup1
      swap2
      sub
      swap1
      return
    tag_8:
      0x0
      dup1
      swap1
      sload
      swap1
      0x100
      exp
      swap1
      div
      0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
      and
      dup2
      jump  // out

    auxdata: 0xa165627a7a72305820dd4c6e28e67e307f6f891abd170c6646cad8d99ce9c533e220d4362c5a3b2ab00029
}
```